# Setting property on object knowing the EntityFramework include expression that was used to retrieve that property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-expressions

Is there a way to set an Entity Objects navigation properties knowing the expression that was used to include this navigation property on the object?

i.e.

````
public class MyGenericBusinessLogic<T> {
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;


    public MyGenericBusinessLogic(DbContext dbContext) {
       _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public U AddItem<U>(int parentId, Expression<Func<T,object>> property, U item) {
        T entity = _dbContext.[DbSet].Queryable.Include(t => t.Property).SingleOrDefault(e => e.id == id);

        //HELP NEEDED HERE
        //now how do i add the ```U item``` to the ```T entity```?

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return item;
    }
}
````

so given that you have the expression above `t => t.Property` is it possible to set that property's value to `U item`?

`entity.[Property] = item`

Comment: can you define what ```_repo``` is?

Comment: tried to make it a bit more clear just using DbContext instance

Comment: sorry, could you add some more context to this question? It's still not clear how you would be using this. Is ```T``` defined, or are you trying to generate a generic object based upon the included properties of the entity you've loaded?

Comment: Could you provide an example what are you trying to achieve? For instance, given `Expression<Func<T, object>> property` and `object value` and you want to execute the property setter with the specified value, or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `Expression<Func<T, object>>` which is valid for `Include`, it's possible to generate property setter using the `Expression` class methods.

However there is no need to do that when working with EF, because the [`DbEntityEntry<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696410(v=vs.103).aspx) class provides a [`Reference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671327(v=vs.103).aspx) method with the exact same argument, which returns a [`DbReferenceEntry<TEntity, TProperty>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696537(v=vs.103).aspx) instance, which in turn has [`CurrentValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679439(v=vs.103).aspx) property which can be used to *get and set* the navigation property value.

The usage could be like this:

```
Expression<Func<T, object>> property = t => t.Property;
T entity = _dbContext.Queryable.Include(property).SingleOrDefault(e => e.id == id);
// Get the property value
var oldValue = _dbContext.Entry(entity).Reference(property).CurrentValue;
// Set the property value
_dbContext.Entry(entity).Reference(property).CurrentValue = newValue;
```

**Update:** The above works for simple (a.k.a. *reference*) navigation properties and not for collections. Here is how you can build a property setter from the property accessor expression:

```
static Expression<Action<T, object>> MakeSetter<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
{
    var member = (MemberExpression)property.Body;
    var source = property.Parameters[0];
    var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
    var body = Expression.Assign(member, Expression.Convert(value, member.Type));
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(body, source, value);
}
```

And the usage:

```
Expression<Func<T, object>> property = t => t.Property;
T entity = _dbContext.Queryable.Include(property).SingleOrDefault(e => e.id == id);
// Get the property value
var oldValue = property.Compile()(entity);
// Set the property value
MakeSetter(property).Compile()(entity, newValue);
```

This way you could get/set collection properties as well. Adding to collection still will be an issue though, but that's another story.

Comment: ok, and what if ```.CurrentValue``` is a List<>? Can I just cast and do a .Add?

Comment: Could you also give an example of how to create the property setter with the Expression class methods? In the actual code the _dbContext is hidden away behind repository patterns so I would need to be able to deal with the returned Entity Object directly to modify values and then just call our unit of work save changes.

Comment: Well, I was assuming you ask for simple (a.k.a. reference) properties. For collections it's more complicated. It requires `Collection` method, which unfortunately requires `Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TProperty>>`, which is not compatible with `Include` expression.

Comment: See the update. Not sure how you can cast to `ICollection<T>` without having `T, except eventually with dynamic or reflection, but this is outside the scope of the current question.

Comment: Marking as answer (ended up not taking this approach)